# Doctrine 2.2 Symfony 2.1 One to Many

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Been trying to do this for awhile now, but i cant seem to get it working....

Basically, we have a page, with multiple contents. Im trying to get it so when entities are generated, we will be able to do something like `$page->getContents()`

when i run the doctrine:generate:entities command tho, it skips the contents property and doesnt create a getter or setter for it....

Is it supposed to? if not, what do i need to do to get this working?

Here are the files:

**Page**

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var integer $pageId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="page_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    public $pageId;

    .......

    /**
     * @var \Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Content 
    *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Content", mappedBy="page", cascade={"all"})
     */
    public $contents;
}
```

**Content**

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Content
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="content")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Content
{
        /**
         * @var integer $contentId
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="content_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        public $contentId;

        .........

        /**
         * @var Page
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="contents")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="page_id")
         * })
         */
        public $page;
}
```

**Schema**

(Taking out unimportant columns)

```
CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `page_id` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `content_id` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`),
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `content_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `page` (`page_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What is the source of your schema ?

Comment: Something seems wrong with your relationship declaration in the schema file/schema source

Comment: edited. worth noting that we do doctrine:mapping:import before, then edit the annotations, etc. then run doctrine:generate:entities

Comment: I see a mappedBy="page" in your annotation but the mapped attribute is called $campaign, seems strange

Comment: Still not working though

Comment: did you generate your entities from your database? If yes, check if your relation is declared in your xml/yml/php orm file you imported (should be in Resources/config/doctrine....)

Comment: That is getting me closer, let me toy with that some more and see if that finally solves my issue. Would you mind putting it in an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @Coussinsky would you mind making that an answer?

Comment: done sorry i didn't get notification for your previous answers...

Comment: no worries, realized i didnt tag you... haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late !

So if you generate your entities from your database you'll have your php entities (usually in Entity\ folder) but also a "mapping file" in xml/yml/php that's created by default in Resources/config/doctrine....

So if you want to make an "fake" relation working you've to declare it in your orm file and your php entity.

Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to validate your entities?

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $validator = new SchemaValidator($em);
    $errors = $validator->validateMapping();
```

Hope this helps
Antonino

Comment: No avail :/, nothing in there